# mui-x-chart stacked bar charts with percentage data

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, mui-x-charts

I am trying to make a stacked bar chart like this in mui-x-charts:

The data source has percentages, and i want the different strengths to be stacked as seen below, where the different colours relate to different strengths of the drug.

[image]

The only way i could see to stack the values was to subtract the values from the preceding value.
The issue is when i do it this way, the hover-tooltip values are not correct:

[image]

i could fall-back to a non-stacked chart easily enough

Q: Any suggestions on how to show the tooltips with correct values and keep the stacked chart as intended?

styles.module.scss

```
.root {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  :global {
    .MuiChartsAxis-directionY .MuiChartsAxis-label {
      transform: translateX(-5px) !important;
    }
  }
}
```

DrugEffectiveness.tsx

```
/**
 * data is from here: https://www.bmj.com/content/326/7404/1423.long
 */

import React, { type ReactNode } from 'react'
import { BarChart } from '@mui/x-charts/BarChart'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'

import styles from './styles.module.scss'

interface reductionType {
  strength: string
  reduction: number | null
}

interface drugType {
  name: string
  reduction: reductionType[]
}

interface seriesType {
  data: Array<number | null>
  label: string
  stack: string
}

const atorvastatin: drugType = {
  name: 'atorvastatin',
  reduction: [
    { strength: '5mg', reduction: 31 },
    { strength: '10mg', reduction: 37 },
    { strength: '20mg', reduction: 43 },
    { strength: '40mg', reduction: 49 },
    { strength: '80mg', reduction: 55 }
  ]
}

const fluvastatin: drugType = {
  name: 'fluvastatin',
  reduction: [
    { strength: '5mg', reduction: 10 },
    { strength: '10mg', reduction: 15 },
    { strength: '20mg', reduction: 21 },
    { strength: '40mg', reduction: 27 },
    { strength: '80mg', reduction: 33 }
  ]
}
const lovastatin: drugType = {
  name: 'lovastatin',
  reduction: [
    { strength: '5mg', reduction: null },
    { strength: '10mg', reduction: 21 },
    { strength: '20mg', reduction: 29 },
    { strength: '40mg', reduction: 37 },
    { strength: '80mg', reduction: 45 }
  ]
}
const pravastatin: drugType = {
  name: 'pravastatin',
  reduction: [
    { strength: '5mg', reduction: 15 },
    { strength: '10mg', reduction: 20 },
    { strength: '20mg', reduction: 24 },
    { strength: '40mg', reduction: 29 },
    { strength: '80mg', reduction: 33 }
  ]
}
const rosuvastatin: drugType = {
  name: 'rosuvastatin',
  reduction: [
    { strength: '5mg', reduction: 38 },
    { strength: '10mg', reduction: 43 },
    { strength: '20mg', reduction: 48 },
    { strength: '40mg', reduction: 53 },
    { strength: '80mg', reduction: 58 }
  ]
}
const simvastatin: drugType = {
  name: 'simvastatin',
  reduction: [
    { strength: '5mg', reduction: 23 },
    { strength: '10mg', reduction: 27 },
    { strength: '20mg', reduction: 32 },
    { strength: '40mg', reduction: 37 },
    { strength: '80mg', reduction: 42 }
  ]
}

const drugs: drugType[] = [atorvastatin, fluvastatin, lovastatin, pravastatin, rosuvastatin, simvastatin]

const strengths: string[] = simvastatin.reduction.map(s => s.strength)

const series5mg: seriesType = { data: [], stack: 'stack', label: '5mg' }
const series10mg: seriesType = { data: [], stack: 'stack', label: '10mg' }
const series20mg: seriesType = { data: [], stack: 'stack', label: '20mg' }
const series40mg: seriesType = { data: [], stack: 'stack', label: '40mg' }
const series80mg: seriesType = { data: [], stack: 'stack', label: '80mg' }

const getReduction = ({ drug, strength }: { drug: drugType, strength: string }): number | null => {
  const filteredDrug = drug.reduction.filter((drugItem: reductionType) => drugItem.strength === strength)
  return filteredDrug.length > 0
    ? filteredDrug[0].reduction
    : null
}
strengths.forEach((strength: string) => {
  drugs.forEach((drug: drugType) => {
    switch (strength) {
      case '5mg' :
        series5mg.data.push(getReduction({ drug, strength }))
        break
      case '10mg':
        series10mg.data.push(Number(getReduction({ drug, strength })) - Number(getReduction({
          drug,
          strength: '5mg'
        })))
        break
      case '20mg':
        series20mg.data.push(Number(getReduction({ drug, strength })) - Number(getReduction({
          drug,
          strength: '10mg'
        })))
        break
      case '40mg':
        series40mg.data.push(Number(getReduction({ drug, strength })) - Number(getReduction({
          drug,
          strength: '20mg'
        })))
        break
      case '80mg':
        series80mg.data.push(Number(getReduction({ drug, strength })) - Number(getReduction({
          drug,
          strength: '40mg'
        })))
        break
    }
  })
})
const valueFormatter = (val: number | null): string => {
  return val !== null ? val + '%' : ''
}

const DrugEffectiveness = (): ReactNode => (
  <div className={`${styles.root} DrugEffectiveness`}>
    <Typography variant="h2">Percentage reduction in LDL cholesterol</Typography>
    <BarChart
      title="tester"
      width={800}
      slotProps={{ legend: { hidden: true } }}
      height={400}
      xAxis={[{
        scaleType: 'band',
        data: drugs.map((d: drugType) => d.name)
      }]}

      series={[
        { ...series5mg, valueFormatter },
        { ...series10mg, valueFormatter },
        { ...series20mg, valueFormatter },
        { ...series40mg, valueFormatter },
        { ...series80mg, valueFormatter }
      ]}
      yAxis={[{
        label: 'Percentage reduction',
        valueFormatter: (v) => v + '%',
        labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 14

        },
        tickLabelStyle: {
          angle: -45,
          textAnchor: 'end',
          fontSize: 12
        }

      }]}
    />
  </div>
)

export default DrugEffectiveness
```